# Check a Connection is still active or not in libpqxx (postgres)

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

How can I check a particular connection has finished it's job or still active in postgres?
I'm creating an array of connections to my database and I want to get a connection which is not in any transaction. I'm using C++ and libpqxx library to connect the database. Can any one tell me how can I check this.

I want to do something like this,

```
 connection* conList;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            conList[i]=new connection("dbname=test user=postgres password=abc123 hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432");
        }

    int i=0;
    while(true)
    {
      if(conList[i] has not any active transaction )
      {
       //do something   
      }
     i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming tbis is because you have a multi-threaded application, you will need to know which thread has which connection anyway. Just use that.

Comment: Exactly, this is a multi threaded application. When I use these connections. It gives me errors like - Started transaction<READ COMMITTED> while transaction<READ COMMITTED> still active

Comment: A thread needs to claim a connection, do what it needs to and hand it back to the pool. You can't rely on the connection's state anyway.